# How to disable "just my code" with dev container

Tags: asp.net, .net, devcontainer

I'm using dotnet 8.
I want to debug packages from nuget,but I can't step in(F11) the source code.

I tried to add following configuration to launch.json,But it's not worked

```
            "justMyCode": false,
            "sourceLinkOptions": {
                "*": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            },
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I can't see any details here neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It's resolved by myside. here is the code

```
"suppressJITOptimizations": true,
"justMyCode": false,
"symbolOptions": {
    "searchPaths": [],
    "searchMicrosoftSymbolServer": true,
    "searchNuGetOrgSymbolServer": true
},
```